# what is the best way to use logger in JSF application

Tags: jsf

what is best way to use logger in JSF application

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question. You're literally asking for a "best way" to use a logger? Which different ways are there then? Please elaborate the actual problem/question.

Comment: i am using netbean, is there any plug-in available  to insert logger code instead of writing it everytime for each method and class.

Comment: You can find the similar answer in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765761/how-to-hide-xhtml-extension-from-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for example using [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/index.html):

```
public class SomeManagedBean {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SomeManagedBean.class);

    public String someAction() {
       logger.debug("Action 'someAction()` executed");
       // some code
    }
}
```

Comment: thank u bozho.. i am using netbeans ide, is there any plug-in available to insert logger code automatically instead of writing it every-time for each method and class.

Comment: not any that I'm aware of. But it is fairly simple ti write it by hand - you'll get used to it.