# Customize FacesServlet <url-pattern> to get rid of .xhtml extension

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, friendly-url

I have `Login.xhtml` and `Home.xhtml`. I configured the url pattern in `web.xml` as follows

```
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>Login.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

When I run the whole project, the login page `URL` is like this `http://localhost:8080/fran/Login.xhtml` , here `fran` is my project name..

However, I would like it to be `http://localhost:8080/fran/Login/` instead of `http://localhost:8080/fran/Login.xhtml`.

How can I achieve this? Is it possible to customize the `<url-pattern>` for every page to get rid of the `.xhtml` extension?

Comment: take a look at http://ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/ , look at the *2. Create pretty-config.xml* example in the main page

Comment: @Daniel ..ya that http://ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces is a good choice.. In `pretty faces` is it require to configure `Pretty filter` in `web.xml`

Comment: [OmniFaces FacesViews](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/facesviews/ExtensionlessURLs) offers a zero-configuration way of getting rid of `.xhtml` extension. It's been used at among others https://showcase.omnifaces.org and https://zeef.com.

Comment: @BalusC..Thanks for your answer..which is very easier to configure...and the documentation which is plotted there was fantastic.. anybody can understand it... i am so happy to use this plugin...thanks for suggestions..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If your sole reason is to get rid of the `.xhtml` extension, then there are various ways depending on the JSF version you're using.

#### Faces 4.0

Just add the following context parameter to `web.xml`:

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>jakarta.faces.AUTOMATIC_EXTENSIONLESS_MAPPING</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

#### JSF 2.3+

JSF 2.3 offers a new API to collect all views: the [`ViewHandler#getViews()`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/faces/application/ViewHandler.html#getViews-javax.faces.context.FacesContext-java.lang.String-javax.faces.application.ViewVisitOption...-). Combine this with [`ServletRegistration#addMapping()`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/ServletRegistration.html#addMapping-java.lang.String...-) in a `ServletContextListener` as below.

```
@FacesConfig
@WebListener
public class ApplicationConfig implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        addExtensionLessMappings(event.getServletContext(), FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
    }

    private void addExtensionLessMappings(ServletContext servletContext, FacesContext facesContext) {
        servletContext
            .getServletRegistrations().values().stream()
            .filter(servlet -> servlet.getClassName().equals(FacesServlet.class.getName()))
            .findAny()
            .ifPresent(facesServlet -> facesContext
                .getApplication()
                .getViewHandler()
                .getViews(facesContext, "/", ViewVisitOption.RETURN_AS_MINIMAL_IMPLICIT_OUTCOME)
                .forEach(view -> facesServlet.addMapping(view))
        );
    }
}
```

Effectively, this is an oneliner. Source: [Arjan Tijms' Blog](https://arjan-tijms.omnifaces.org/p/jsf-23.html#1435) and [The Definitive Guide to JSF](https://github.com/omnifaces/definitive-guide-to-jsf-in-javaee8).

If you're using MyFaces as JSF 2.3 implementation, then this can be transparently activated by solely the following `web.xml` context parameter:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.AUTOMATIC_EXTENSIONLESS_MAPPING</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Mojarra does not have an equivalent yet.

#### JSF 2.2-

Use [OmniFaces FacesViews](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/facesviews/ExtensionlessURLs). It offers a zero-configuration way to achieve that by placing the view files in `/WEB-INF/faces-views/` folder. Otherwise, if you intend to not modify your project structure and want to keep your view files at the usual place and still benefit of extensionless URLs, then it's a matter of adding the following context parameter:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.omnifaces.FACES_VIEWS_SCAN_PATHS</param-name>
    <param-value>/*.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

In case you don't want to use OmniFaces, but rather want to homegrow your own, just look at [source code](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/tree/master/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/facesviews) of OmniFaces. It's open source under Apache 2.0 License. It's only not an oneliner.

Comment: `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()` returns `null` for me.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [prettyfaces: Pretty URLs for JavaServer Faces](http://ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces) ,

Look at the *2. Create pretty-config.xml example* in the main page

And take a look at the [Chapter 2. Get Started](http://ocpsoft.org/docs/prettyfaces/3.3.0/en-US/html/GettingStarted.html)

Comment: ya.. that's right.. my question, Is it require to configure Pretty filter in web.xml  .. In step 2(as you mentioned) is only for `pretty-config.xml`configuration,Is this part only alone..?

Comment: @Daniel thanks for pointing out prettyfaces -- it looks like it will solve the problem I have which is making the URLs more user friendly

Answer (score 0):

Just a little complement to mr. @balusc excelent answer about MyFaces on JSF 2.3... (Edit: not really a complement as one can not complement what's complete, but just a workaround for tomcat/tomee users to deal with this tomcat bug).

Using MyFaces 2.3.6, I received a Exception talking about servlet specification and ServletContextListener:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Section 4.4 of the Servlet 3.0 specification does not permit this method to be called from a ServletContextListener that was not defined in web.xml, a web-fragment.xml file nor annotated with @WebListener
```

Following the stack i saw this line:

```
at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.contextInitialized(StartupServletContextListener.java:103)
```

And after adding that listener to web.xml all worked fine:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: This happens only when you're using Tomcat instead of a normal JEE server and this is actually a bug in Tomcat itself.

Comment: Impressive! I was using TomEE 8.0.5. indeed.
I checked. MyFaces has the correct web-fragment, with this exact Listener. Really a tomcat bug. Thank you, sir.