# Get rid of .xhtml extension

Tags: spring, jsf, jsf-2.2, url-pattern

I have sought way to get rid of .xhtml extension, so that it is:

```
www.mysystem.com/view/login
```

rather than

```
www.mysystem.com/view/login.xhtml
```

I found some solutions, but all always use omnifaces, like this:
[Customize FacesServlet <url-pattern> to get rid of .xhtml extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18508329/customize-facesservlet-url-pattern-to-get-rid-of-xhtml-extension)

and I wouldn't want to use the omnifaces in my project. Currently I use JSF 2.2 and Spring Framework.

There is a way to get rid of the extension?

Comment: Use PrettyFaces…  or don't you want to use that either? Then download the source of either and take out the code you like (if the license allows) and use that in you project,  maintain bugfixes yourself etc…  simply put:use omnifaces

Comment: OmniFaces is open source. Just copypaste/write the same code. This is absolutely not answerable with a few lines of code or so.